# android gradle 3.2.1 to 3.3.1 breaks String resources using CDATA

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources, cdata, double-quotes

All my resources String are using CDATA to escape HTML and simple quotes if any are present.
Most don't really need it but my resources files are generated from Excel and it makes it easier to handle.

Everything was working perfectly well until I upgraded from gradle 3.2.1 to gradle 3.3.1

Now all my string from xml resources are displayed surrounded with double quotes. If I revert to 3.2.1 everything is good again.

Why do I use CDATA in my string resources ?
Most of the resource string I use in my app are kept in an Excel file, so I can easyly handle traductions, updates are made by my project reviewers,... 
They can use a tool thas is handy for them and don't bother with escaping quotes or HTML.

And my resources files are generated with formulas and macro easily.

Because some resources may contain HTML, or may need quote escape, I do surround all resources with CDATA

```
<string name="action_settings"><![CDATA["Settings"]]></string>
<string name="alert_too_long"><![CDATA["<font color='red'>You took too long to answer.<b> Learn better and try again.</font>"]]></string>
```

If I remove the quotes in CDATA it displays well but simple quotes need escaping.

Is there a setting in this new version of Gradle or any reason for this change ?